# The import com.perfectomobile.selenium cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, perfecto

I have installed `PerfectoMobile` plug-in for Eclipse and was able to connect to Perfecto lab from Eclipse. I am trying to write the selenium automation code but the following `WebDriver` class is never recognized.

```
MobileDriver driver = new MobileDriver("mobilecloud.perfectomobile.com","username","password");
```

Where do we import the jar file for `com.perfectomobile.selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that when I create a new project of type *Perfecto Lab Java Selenium Project* I see the jar file for `com.perfectomobile.selenium` added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 :** Download and Install the perfecto plugin from : https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/PD/IDE+Plugin+Installation

**Step2 :** 
on your IDE : Navigate to  `File > Settings` (depends on your IDE)
for `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.7` navigate to this :

[image]

**Step3 :** (remember you installed the plugin in **step 1**

[image]

**Step4 :** Add a module (give it a Name eg. "Perfecto_module")

Once done you will see this

[image]

Now its up-to you how you want to utilise this in your project, Good luck !